# Failed to define Vue single file component (CLI) in Loop, like app->A->B->A->B

Tags: loops, vue.js, components, command-line-interface

I am trying to define components in loop, i.e. components are referring each other in loop.

The structure is like this:

```
app(root) -> A -> B -> A -> B....,
```

However, I received error msg:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

**app.vue:**

```
<template>
   <ComponentA></ComponentA>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA.vue";

export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
        ComponentA
    }
};
</script>
```

**ComponentA.vue:**

```
<template>
   <div>
      ComponentA
      <ComponentB></ComponentB>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB.vue";

export default {
    name: "ComponentA",
    components: {
        ComponentB
    }
};
</script>
```

**CompoentB.vue:**

```
<template>
   <div>
      ComponentB
      <ComponentA></ComponentA>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentA from "./ComponentA.vue";
export default {
    name: "ComponentB",
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$options.components.ComponentA = require("./ComponentA");
    },
    components: { ComponentA }
};
</script>
```

**Question:**

I need this structure in my application, how to make this definition working?

**Notes:**

1. I am using CLI, i.e. single vue file component, it seems like webpack is supporting this, since if I use vue.js as a plugin, it is working, but not in cli environment.
2. I also tried this in componentB, but not working:

   `beforeCreate() {
       this.$options.components.ComponentA = require("./ComponentA");
   }`
3. Recursive component is working, i.e. component is referring to itself in definition, but components referring to each other in loops does not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out myself:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components

it should be:

```
beforeCreate() {
    this.$options.components.ComponentA = require("./ComponentA").default;
},
```